# In modern game design, which portions of the game are written to be portable?

Tags: c++, opengl, directx

Say you're a big company and making a huge, blockbuster title that is going to target the PC, Mac, Xbox, and the PS3. And let's say that you chose C++, as most studios tend to do. Which portions of it do you write to be portable code? Is it possible to truly write a portable game? Do you have to rewrite the rendering engine and user interface if you go to a new platform?

Comment: As much as reasonably possible I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An educated guess is that everything except hardware dependent code is written to be portable. I.e. game logic, vector graphics, sounds (?) are (quite) portable, graphical output, memory management, timing is not (always).

With a good choice of libraries one can probably maximise the amount of portable code.

Answer (score 1):

You sure can't ask your PC gamers to use a 360 controller.

The rendering and user interface must be re-done from scratch, at least. Also, in addition, it's likely that other OS-dependent functions like networking must be reformed. After all, `boost::asio` probably doesn't function on a PS3. Some other processor-specific stuff like vectorization

However, ideally, a game would utilize as much portable code as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I would assume if there is a physics engine, that would be portable. Also would be player systems, such as health, inventory, NPC behavior and so on would be platform independent. You would have to rewrite the rendering engine most likely depending on what console the game is so for. The user interaction might have a bit of rewriting due to having to interact with a different controller which would most likely be accessed differently in each console.

In general if the code interacts with the API for the console, rendering, vectorization, User interface, input and so on would have to be rewritten. The base code like physics, basic behaviors, the Ai, and health inventory management wouldn't really have to be rewritten.

So in the end: **If it's hardware dependent, it will have to be rewritten or refactored.**

Answer (score 1):

Adhering to the DRY principle also leads to more portable code, since any non-portable code is localized.

For example, avoid doing this multiple times in your code:

```
#if defined(PC)
  // create a network connection PC-style
#elif defined(XBOX)
  // create a network connection XBox-style
#elif defined(MAC)
  // create a network connection Mac-style
#elif defined(PS3)
  // create a network connection PS3-style
#endif
```

and instead, do it once and create a function

```
createNetworkConnection();
```

that you use in multiple places.